# How to interpret functions that are defined in terms of $\text{argmax}$ in optimization?

Tags: optimization, soft-question, algorithms, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

In optimization, sometimes you encounter functions or difference equations defined in terms of $\text{argmin}$ or $\text{argmax}$

> $p: X \to X, x \mapsto \text{argmin}_{y \in X} \phi(y) + \|x-y\|^2$

I am puzzled by the fact we need to solve an optimization algorithm in order to evaluate these functions.

For example, consider   $p: X \to X, x \mapsto \text{argmin}_{y \in X} \phi(y) + \|x-y\|^2$ .

On the one hand, the interpretation of this function is clear. Given a vector $x \in X$, we map it to a vector that gives the minimum of $\phi(y) + \|x-y\|^2$.

But on the other hand, we have no idea of this map is even well defined, since it is well known in optimization this map $\text{argmin}$ could have one, multiple, or no solution. So given a sequence of $x_k$, $p(x_k)$ could yield something like $y_1, \{y_{21},y_{22}\}, \text{no solution}, y_4, ...$

Further, it is not at all clear how this minimizer $y$ is found, it is usually not stated as part of the function. I would be much happier if the function was defined as "$p: X \to X, x \mapsto \text{argmin}_{y \in X} \phi(y) + \|x-y\|^2$ where we solve for $y$ using ... algorithm which guarantees a unique minimizer"

How do people in optimization deal with this ambiguity.

Comment: The prox mapping you defined about is usually considered on the space of functions which are *convex lower semi-continuous* on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$. This function space is usually denoted $\Gamma_0(\mathcal H)$. For $f \in \Gamma_0(\mathcal H)$, the prox $p_f$ defines an "unambiguous" function from $\mathcal H$ to itself. It also corresponds to the derivative of the *inf-convolution* of $f$ with the quadrance $\frac{1}{2}\|.\|_2^2$ (called the *Moreau envelope* of $f$). More on proximal calculus can be found in this one-page manuscript https://people.ok.ubc.ca/bauschke/Research/68.pdf

Comment: If you can read french, a more complete reference is here: http://www.mat.ufpb.br/jmbo/papers/Brezis/BSMF_1965__93__273_0.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question: indeed, one has to take care when defining a mapping like this to ensure that the solution to the minimization/maximization is unique.

Fortunately, in this case, we likely have that. The specific mapping you have chosen here is the *proximal mapping*, and in the convex optimization settings where it is often found, the function $\phi$ is convex (although not necessarily differentiable). If that is the case, then the squared term $\|x-y\|_2^2$ makes the function *strongly convex*, which guarantees that the minimization will yield a single, unique solution.

Regarding your second question. The practice of mathematics does *not* require that the algorithm for solving an optimization problem be provided before that problem can be studied, or before anything useful can be said about it. That's a good thing, because there simply is no way one can define a single, universal, practical algorithm for solving optimization problems, even convex ones.

Take the specific example of the proximal map: the solution method depends *critically* on the choice of $\phi(x)$. For some choices, like $\phi(x)=\|x\|_1$, the solution can be obtained analytically. For others, an iterative numerical approach (like a gradient search or Newton method) is required. Thus while there are general principles and patterns that can guide you, the solution method must be determined on a case-by-case basis.

But again, there is quite a bit we can *say* about the proximal mapping before we ever get around to solving it.

Comment: Hi thanks 4 ur excellent answer! can you take a look at my other question specifically regarding optimization algorithms? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254107/why-are-optimization-algorithms-defined-in-terms-of-other-optimization-problems